# NoSuchFileException adding file to ZIP using Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I have a frustrating issue using the Java NIO to add files to existing ZIPs.

On a test of 2500 files, 2 or 3 will fail. I am adding files to the root of the ZIP and not in a subfolder (which appears to be the source of some issues in other posts).

The weird thing is that the file cited in the exception message it claims doesn't exist is neither the ZIP or the file being added, but the temporary file created by Java as it builds a new ZIP file. Here is the code (less the try/catch):

```
Map<String, String> zipProps = new HashMap<>();
zipProps.put("create", "false");
zipProps.put("encoding", "UTF-8");
FileSystem zipFs = null;

URI zipAsFileSys = new URI("jar", fileToArchive.toURI().toString(), null);
zipFs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zipAsFileSys, zipProps);
Path pathToNewFileInZip = zipFs.getPath(fileIdFile.getName());
Path pathToNewFileOnDisk = Paths.get(fileIdFile.getAbsolutePath());
Files.createFile(pathToNewFileInZip ); //Added later. No difference.
Files.copy(pathToNewFileOnDisk, pathToNewFileInZip, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
if(zipFs!=null) zipFs.close();
```

And the exception:

```
Exception: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \\Server\archives\zipfstmp7224673021628877485.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

This was ultimately traced to network latency and/or Windows caching when manipulating files on a remote drive.

Seems Java can't figure out that the file it just created actually exists. It would be nice if it was possible to get a handle on the tmp file to see if it exists.

Seeing as I don't have the ability to mess with the OS caching, I never found a good workaround other than introducing a delay before the Files.copy(...) call, and because our production environment doesn't use multiple servers for this exact task, it isn't stopping me from proceeding.